# How to show the content in the same page at the right with TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have downloaded TinyMCE and extract it on the project directory.
The html part.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="container_left">
        <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit">            
</div>
<div id="show_right"></div>
</div>
```

The css part.

```
body{
    width:1000px;
    height:800px;
    border:1px solid  black;
}
#container_left{
    width:40%;
    height:80%;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
#mytextarea{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#show_right{
    width:40%;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:right;
}
```

The left part is a textarea,you can input some text in it and modify it with tinymce;i want to show the content on the right part after you click the submit button.

The js part.

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
    });
</script>
</script>
<script>
function showAtRight()
{
    var content = document.getElementById("mytextarea").value;
    var target = document.getElementById("show_right");
    target.innerHTML = content;
}

ob = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
ob.addEventListener("click",showAtRight);
</script>
```

Why can't show the content in the left on my right part after inputting `it is a test` on the left `container_left` and press button `submit`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once TinyMCE appears on the page the underlying `textarea` is no longer visible on the page - you are typing into an `iFrame`.  Targeting the original `textarea` won't do what you want because the content is not there.  You can use TinyMCE's APIs to get the content and update the `div`.  Here is an example:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Gegaab/7